# Oracle Database object File backup

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i take a backup of all database objects(table schema, procedure, function)
and store it in my windows file location every night. I'm connecting using PL/SQL Developer to oracle server located at different location.

To put in short words "I should have backup in my machine rather than the server", Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed them as part of your Oracle client installation, you could use the [Oracle Export and Import utilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#i1023560) to create a logical backup on your client machine.

On the other hand, I would strongly question the wisdom of this requirement.  Your DBA ought to be quite concerned about someone generating regular exports of their database that are not under the same controls as the normal backups to prevent them falling into the wrong hands.  You're also copying all the data from the database over the network on a regular basis-- that is going to put a substantial load on the database and on the network that are likely to draw the attention of DBAs and network admins.

Comment: I only want to copy the  the table schema & programming objects not the data. My estimate is it shouldn't take more than 2mb of disk space.

Comment: @user841683 - You can do an export without data.  If you just want a backup of the structure of the table, that should create fewer objections from the DBA.  But the DBA would almost certainly still prefer to schedule and run the backups him- or herself particularly if you're going to ask the DBA to restore an object in the event of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To back up backup sets from disk to tape:

```
If you are backing up a subset of available backup sets, then execute the LIST BACKUPSET command to obtain their primary keys.

The following example lists the backup sets in summary form:

RMAN> LIST BACKUPSET SUMMARY;

List of Backups
===============
Key TY LV S Device Type Completion Time #Pieces #Copies Comp Tag
--- -- -- - ----------- --------------- ------- ------- ---- ---
1   B  F  A DISK        28-MAY-07       1       1       NO   TAG20070528T132432
2   B  F  A DISK        29-MAY-07       1       1       NO   TAG20070529T132433
3   B  F  A DISK        30-MAY-07       1       1       NO   TAG20070530T132434

The following example lists details about backup set 3:

RMAN> LIST BACKUPSET 3;

List of Backup Sets
===================

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
3       Full    8.33M      DISK        00:00:01     30-MAY-07
        BP Key: 3   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20070530T132434
        Piece Name: /disk1/oracle/dbs/c-35764265-20070530-02
  Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 397221       Ckp time: 30-MAY-07
  SPFILE Included: Modification time: 30-MAY-07
  SPFILE db_unique_name: PROD
```

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the answer. Could you be a bit more specific about how the list backupset command (which lists the backup set) enables the user to copy individual backups? Knowing where the backups are stored is great but you should address how to copy them in order to fully answer the question.